# Getting "Pages Public Content Access requires either app secret proof or an app token"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am trying to access the comments on my page and while trying to fetch those using FB JS SDK, i am getting content access auth error.

"**(#100) Pages Public Content Access requires either app secret proof or an app token**".

My App is currently in development mode. i have already added below permission:
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_metadata
pages_read_user_content

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you using app secret proof or an app token like the error message say?

Comment: Hi Wiz, I am using FB Javascript SDK, in which app id and version is provided. I also have app secret but not using it any where, because i am not using any java social dependency or backend APIs/process.

Comment: What kind of token are you using, user or page?

Comment: Hi CBroe, As per the JS SDK docs, once login is completed it uses the user token to access the information.

Comment: Admin of the page, or just any user? Did you try with a page access token?